# Mesh repair/transform into a proper 3D model

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-printing

I made a 3d model using photogrammetry, it should be an old piece of furniture which unfortunately was in a corner, so I was able to make a partial acquisition.
I would like to fix it, even roughly, to print it in 3D, how do you suggest I proceed?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you want to print it, I'd suggest to remodel it from scratch. It will be easier than trying to close every hole in the scanned model and trying to make it look natural (as you'd have to probably also sculpt it after closing it so that the new faces are not perfectly straight etc.) It will be very easy to remodel as you can use this model as a guide and snap to its vertices